# Rational functions: reciprocal of linear and quadratic functions: center of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections, rational-functions

When one graphs rational functions in Pre-Calculus type course, one usually graphs functions that are reciprocals of linear functions and reciprocals of quadratics.
One of the other properties that maybe asked is to find the invariant points.
Sometimes the invariant points correspond to the center of curvature of the arms of the hyperbolas that are created from these functions.

Is there a way to determine the center of curvature for the hyperbola arms of these rational functions without using Calculus based methods.
When i say center of curvature that means i am looking for the coordinates(x,y) of the center.
To make this more clear I have added an image i generated:
[image]

As you can see, I put the quadratic as well to get intersection with the reciprocal which gives the invariant points. I thought I would try to add a line that connect the peak of the bottom quadratic like parabola with vertical asymptote, but it went lower than the center of curvature of the hyperbolic arm. (The line is in green color)

I just looked at the graph and decided to try to put a line thru the asymptote at x =2 to with a slope of 1, and it looks like its going thru the center of curvature of the hyperbolic arm.
See attached image, the new line is in orange color:
[image]

Also wish to add further analogy to the actual conic section Hyperbola, in this the center is called the Vertex of the Hyperbola. See attached image:
[image]

I also want to note something I just noticed, that the line that goes thru the hyperbolic arms of this reciprocal quadratic, cuts the arms in a very symmetrical way such that the line acts like a mirror, cutting it symmetrically in half.

Comment: $y = 1 / (x^2-4)$ is not a hyperbola. What is your definition for `center of curvature`?

Comment: Yes, I know, I made that clear that its not a hyperbola. I said this rational has hyperbolic arms. It is well known from conic sections that these types of functions have a center/vertex like structure. I know that in differential geometry they would discuss the concept of curvature, which the greatest rate of change on a section of the curve. I had friends in university who took course on differential geometry, and tried to explain these things to me. I took other maths like complex analysis, I wish i had taken differential geometry.

Comment: I am trying to visualize the center of curvature thru the graphs, i believe its obvious. For a more rigorous definition, I need help from people on this forum, because if i knew the rigorous proper definition, I would know how to do this.

Comment: So, I added an additional image of an actual Hyperbola. In this Hyperbola, the thing they call the Vertex, is what I called the center of curvature. See last image above.

Comment: The [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) has an axis of symmetry, and its vertices have a clear-cut definition. Your curve has neither. The [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_plane_curves) is well-defined point-wise, but it's not clear what you mean by "*center of curvature*" for an entire curve here, or even if it's related. `For a more rigorous definition, I need help from people on this forum` But you first need to spell out what exactly it is that you are after.

Comment: You seem to want to identify the pt where one "arm" of your curve-of-interest ends and the other arm begins. The lack of symmetry in the arms makes this tricky, but one possible definition is "the point of maximal curvature". "Curavature", here, is formally defined, via Calculus, as the reciprocal of the radius of the ["osculating circle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle), which best approximates the curve (very!) near the point in question. (BTW: the term "center of curvature" is reserved for the center of that circle; you'll want to choose something else for your notion.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Blue, so it seems one has to go into the area of Differential Geometry to figure this out. I was already researching the "osculating circle". I like the term you mentioned : " the point of Maximal Curvature". I will make note of this term. SO I hope that people who are knowledgeable about Differential Geometry can also help out with this question of mine. Thanks again BLUE for your words, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Palu: Glad to help! By the way ... "Differential Geometry" is more advanced than is needed here. Finding point(s) of maximum curvature on a curve, especially one of your specific curves-of-interest, requires only elementary Calculus. The [curvature formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions) involves only a few polynomial derivatives, and maximizing the value involves just a couple more. (The resulting polynomial may not have nice roots, though.) I don't have time to post a full solution at the moment; if someone doesn't beat me to it, I'll try later.

Comment: Hi Blue, thanks for you all this great info. If you can post a solution computation, I will award this question to you.